# Update asp.net datalist field, without refreshing , when value changes in database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, real-time, datalist

I have an aspx page that shows a list of students in a databound datalist in card view layout ( i.e repeatcolumns = 5 and repeatdirection=horizontal ).

The properties displayed are - Student Name, Id and Status. The Status field is constantly updated by another external service.

Is it possible to show the new status of the particular student for whom the status has changed in the DB without having to refresh the entire page?

What i'm trying to achieve is a real time monitoring system that a tutor could use to view student activity in a lab.

Thanks
Arvind

Answer (score 1):

You could use an update panel and then set a timer to refresh the update panel and re bind the datagrid with the new data.

Comment: hmm.. thanks but will it work in this scenario - "on first time load, i have 10 students who all are shown as online. A few minutes later, 3 of them go offline. The page should now display all the 10 students, but 7 as online and 3 as offline. i.e only the 3 student status needs to be changed. For this, i want to be able to pull the data of only those students and update corresponding 3 items in the datalist." What you have recommended will no doubt refresh the entire grid.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine does it really matter if the whole grid refreshes but then still displays the same information as it was before it refreshed?

Comment: Is it possible to minimize the data that gets fetched and transferred ? The whole grid would mean a lot of data. Is it possible to ajax enable the Status field alone such that it waits for an asynchronous callback from the server when the status does change on the server? I'm not sure if this is clear enough. Anyway thanks.